# How to solve greater or equal relation between two numbers

Tags: coq

I have two natural numbers a & b. Third number is c which is greater or equal to b (c>=b). Now have following conditions for a & b and want to prove
c greater than a.

```
 a < b->
 c >= a->
 c > a.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know `c >= b` and `b > a` then it's only logical that `c > a`. This kind of reasoning is easily taken care of by the `lia` tactic, which automates reasoning about linear integer arithmetic.

```
From Coq Require Import Lia.

Goal forall a b c : nat, a < b -> b <= c -> a <= c.
Proof.
  intros.
  lia.
Qed.
```

Comment: Goal forall a b c : nat, a < b -> b <= c -> a < c . Under what conditions it could be possible Second H1:a <> 0 
H2: a>=b
H3: a<=b.
What result we can extract from H2 &H3.
what possible relation between a & b can be derive.
(a<>b  or a=b)